# Firebase Android reset password in custom Login (not with email authentication)

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using my own custom login by custom Id-Password, instead of the email authentication by FirebaseAuth.
I have written the code for resetting the user's password, that if the OLD password entered matches the one in the database, then the NEW password must overwrite the old one in the database.
But, I am facing a silly problem that, after saving the changes to the database my code runs the "else" condition from the initial login authentication(as it didn't match the user's present sign-in credentials matching with the current newly updated ones)
And as a result, a toast appears after the "Password changed" that, "Wrong Password".

What could be a solution to this little issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this problem solved by generating a different way for marking wrong password at login instead of giving a toast. :)